# Getting an "Enter Passphrase" box at boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, encryption, ecryptfs

I have upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 today. On 14.10, I did have my home folder encrypted. I have never had to enter a passphrase before (except the initial setting of it).

Right after upgrading to 15.04 this evening, I now have a box that I need to enter a passphrase before I get to my login password (they are the same password).

I do not recall having chosen anything about full disk encryption during the upgrade (it just upgraded existing apps and OS).

Why am I seeing that box now and what can I do to just go back to entering my password to login without the whole passphrase box? I do want a secure laptop but thought I had that before without this new box at boot up.